# Unable to access application cache Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Can not access application cache on Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1

I usually access my application cache while debugging until i recently noticed that files in cache folder are now all hidden, is it just me or Android Studio's no longer provide cache access?